# How do I zip a folder with 7-zip but not subfolders of that folder?

Tags: windows, 7-zip

For instance, if I wanted to zip everything in My Documents, but not subfolders in My Documents, and I also did not know the name of each subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command prompt and if 7-Zip is not in your path, navigate to the directory with the 7-Zip files, then type:

```
7z.exe a C:\mydocs.7z -r- %userprofile%\documents\*.*
```

This just zips all in files in documents but not any subfolders.

If you are using a Pre-Vista Windows, the example above may not work unless you have a 'documents' folder in your home directory.

The 7-Zip help file has examples for all the command line options.

Comment: And if you are using a Post-XP Windows, the example above will result in mydocs.7z ending up in `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore` due to UAC and especially [Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756960.aspx) (since even Admin users have no rights to write to the root dir i.e. C:\).

Comment: @Karan - Correct, I just wanted to give a short example. Still, I always have an elevated command prompt open where the example works fine.

Comment: Yep, an elevated cmd prompt will do the trick. Nothing wrong with the example though, was just an add-on comment (since you mentioned a Pre-Vista caveat yourself).

Comment: Well, it runs into problems if you have files named without extensions such as README or LICENSE, but for most normal directories this works fine.